# how to render static 3d object in certain coordinates unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, rendering

This is my first time with unity, I need to make a 3d object in the camera of the device (vr) in certain coordinates of a map, do you know any links that can help me? Is only a static object will always be in the same position and users will be able to see it on their devices

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be overlayed above a 3D scene use a [renderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html), then add the rendered texture to the UI using a [Raw Image component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html).

Another way to do this is to use a canvas set to screen space overlay rendering. You can create a canvas by going to GameObject > UI > Image.
(see page for UI>canvas on Unity manual site, I can only post 2 links as a new user)

The canvas in this rendering mode is described this way on the unity manual page for the UI Canvas:

> Screen Space - Overlay
>   This render mode places UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene. If the screen is resized or changes resolution, the Canvas will automatically change size to match this.

I am assuming this is a UI element over a 3D scene, because you mentioned VR.

Credit: I got some of my links and info from the unity forum thread "What is the best way to display 3D models as UI elements?"